# Simple SQL query from table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

For my CIS class, I have SQL project, and this is the first time I'm working with SQL, doing okay but I can't do one of the queries. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I tried:

```
Select cno, cname
from customer
where 
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal attempt at answering the question in the form of a SQL query for us to aid you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it, I just edited.

Comment: And what were your results?

Comment: Are you asking if you provided the correct answer?  At first glance it looks fine to me.

Comment: I checked with my professor, and she said I'm very close. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It may depend on how you interpret the question.  Does she mean a customer that buys both books "Financial Accounting" AND "Cost Accounting".  You are using IN which is equivalent of "Financial Accounting" OR "Cost Accounting".

Comment: She did say make sure its "Financial Accounting" AND "Cost Accounting". But since this is my first SQL project, I didn't really understand what she meant. So are you saying change IN to AND? 
Select cno, cname
from customer
where cno AND (select cno
  from salesorder
  where ono AND (select ono
  from orderline
  where bno AND (select bno
    from book
    where bname AND ('Financial Accounting', 
      'Cost Accounting')
    )
   )
  )

Comment: You'll have to use AND... this is a customer that has purchased both books.  When you say IN (....) it is a customer that has purchased either book or both books.  I'll try posting a possible solution.

Comment: @Soft_ibo: No, you shall not change `IN` to `AND`. The expression `bname IN ('Financial Accounting', 'Cost Accounting')` is the same as `bname = 'Financial Accounting' OR bname = 'Cost Accounting'`, so you get orders where one book *or* the other matches. You must find a way to place an `AND`such that you get customers who bough one book *and* the other. See my answer on this. It is very simple after all :-)

Comment: I wrote the same query as Thorsten, just using equals for the book string name.  ex. `where bno = (select bno from book where bname = 'Financial Accounting')`  Instead of `where bno IN (select bno from book where bname = 'Financial Accounting')`  Syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Zorkolot: You are right. We should expect only one book to be called 'Financial Accounting' and hence use `=` instead of `IN`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use two `IN` clauses, one for 'Financial Accounting', one for 'Cost Accounting'.

```
Select cno, cname
from customer
where cno in 
(
  select cno
  from salesorder
  where ono in 
  (
    select ono 
    from orderline 
    where bno in (select bno from book where bname = 'Financial Accounting')
  )
)
and cno in 
(
  select cno
  from salesorder
  where ono in 
  (
    select ono 
    from orderline 
    where bno in (select bno from book where bname = 'Cost Accounting')
  )
);
```

Rob M's solution is more elegant, whereas above query should be more along the lines what you've learned so far.

Comment: Agreed.  Based on the instructor's evaluation of what you have so far, Thorsten's answer is probably more appropriate, unless you've already learned joins and aggregates/grouping.

Comment: Not yet! :) SQL seems fun but a little bit confusing. Hopefully, it will get easier with some more practice.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't exactly clear on whether the customer needs to have ordered both books in one order or across multiple orders. I'll assume the latter, based on the data provided.

Your answer returns customers who ordered either (or both) of those books.  You say you want customers who order both books.  Also, it's hard to keep your code straight when nesting several subqueries.  Most people prefer joins.

This query should work for you.

```
select cno,cname from customer where cno in (
    select o.cno
    from salesorder o  
        inner join orderline ol on o.ono=ol.ono
        inner join book b on b.bno=ol.bno
    where b.bname in ('Financial Accounting', 'Cost Accounting')
    group by o.cno
    having count(distinct b.bno) = 2 -- Require both separate books, not 2 of one book or the other      
)
```

Here is a complete example in SQL Server:

```
declare @book table (bno int, bname varchar(50))
insert @book (bno,bname) values
(10501,'Forensic Accounting')
,(10704,'Financial Accounting')
,(10933,'Cost Accounting')
declare @orderline table (ono int, bno int) 
insert @orderline (ono,bno) VALUES
(1020,10501)
,(1020,10502)
,(1020,10503)
,(1020,10504)
,(1021,10605)
,(1022,10605)
,(1022,10704)
,(1023,10879)
,(1023,10988)
,(1024,10502)
,(1024,10988)
,(1026,10933)
,(1027,10933)
,(1028,10933)
,(1028,10965)
,(1029,10933)
,(1029,10965)
,(1029,10988)
,(1030,10965)
declare @salesorder table (ono int, cno int)
insert @salesorder (ono,cno) VALUES
(1020,23511)
,(1021,23513)
,(1022,23513)
,(1023,23512)
,(1024,23511)
,(1025,23511)
,(1026,23511)
,(1027,23512)
,(1028,23512)
,(1029,23513)
,(1030,23511)
declare @customer table (cno int, cname varchar(20))
insert @customer (cno,cname) values 
(23511,'a')
,(23512,'b')
,(23513,'c')
,(23514,'d')
,(23515,'e')
,(23516,'f')
,(23517,'g')
,(23518,'h')

select cno,cname from @customer where cno in (
    select o.cno
    from @salesorder o  
        inner join @orderline ol on o.ono=ol.ono
        inner join @book b on b.bno=ol.bno
    where b.bname in ('Financial Accounting', 'Cost Accounting')
    group by o.cno
    having count(distinct b.bno) = 2 -- Require both separate books, not 2 of one book or the other      
)
```